# Tensorflow: how to look up and average a different amount of embedding vectors per training instance, with multiple training instances per minibatch?

Tags: tensorflow, embedding-lookup

In a recommender system setting: let's say I want to learn to predict future item purchases based on user past purchases using an approach inspired by [Youtube's recommender system](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2959190):

[image]

Concretely, let's say I have a **trainable** content-based network that receives as input an item and, based on its content, returns an embedding for such item. Now, let's say each user has purchased a **variable number** of items in the past (some users might have purchased 5 items, others maybe 1, others maybe 10, some outliers maybe 100, etc.). I want to generate a **user vector**, a **candidate item vector** and then a **user-item match score** as follows:

1. I map each item purchased by that user to its embedded item vector using the trainable content-based network
2. I calculate the average of all those embedded item vectors (as illustrated in the picture)
3. I apply a couple of ReLu layers on top of this average, thus obtaining a **user vector**
4. I map a **candidate item** (to be recommended) to its embedded item vector using the same trainable content-based network of step 1 (the weights of this network are always shared, like a Siamese network so to speak)
5. Finally, I compute the dot product between the user vector and the candidate item vector, apply a cross entropy loss during training, etc.

So my question is about the technical details of **how to implement the embedding lookup and average of a variable number of embedded item vectors per user using Tensorflow**. For example, think of a mini-batch with, say, 100 training instances. Each training instance in the mini-batch possibly consists of a different user with a different amount of purchased items in the past. Although the context is different, my question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44757164/tensorflow-embedding-lookup-with-unequal-sized-lists), but unfortunately nobody has answered that question up to now.

Comment: I'm currently trying to figure this out myself; did you ever manage to find a way to do this?

Comment: I don't remember the code right know, but I ended up using padding and masking

Comment: thanks, that's what I ended up doing too :)